# Determine the number of pymongo documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

When specifying the number of documents in pymongo , does it retrieve all the documents and then limit them using Python code, or does it fetch only 10 documents directly from the server?

For example, is this :

```
data=mydb[collection].find().limit(10)
```

like this ?:

```
data=mydb[collection].find()
data=data.limit(10)
```

If so, what is the way to limit the number of records so that only 10 documents come from the server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fetches only 10. Remember that PyMongo returns a cursor. Data is only retrieved after starting the iteration on the cursor.

If you wonder, it simply adds a [`$limit`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) aggregation to the pipeline that is requested from the server.